# Defining "path" to object key with a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to define a "path" to an `object` key?

For instance if you have an `object`:

```
var obj = {
    hello: {
        you: "you"
    }
}
```

I would like to select it like this:

```
var path = "hello.you";
obj[path]; //Should return "you"
```

(Doesn't work obviously, but is there a way?)

Comment: I haven't seen any ready made method, but you can write one easily

Comment: If you are sure in `path` then you can use `eval("obj." + path);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var path = "hello.you";
eval("obj."+path);
```

Comment: This will obviously totally fail if you have properties with "non-safe" characters. For instance you won't be able to access obj['super-mega'].

Answer (score 5):

Quick code, you probably should make it error proof ;-)

```
var obj = {
    hello: {
        you: "you"
    }
};

Object.prototype.getByPath = function (key) {
  var keys = key.split('.'),
      obj = this;

  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      obj = obj[keys[i]];
  }

  return obj;
};

console.log(obj.getByPath('hello.you'));
```

And here you can test -> http://jsbin.com/ehayav/2/

mz

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that but you can write function that will traverse nested object

```
function get(object, path) {
   path = path.split('.');
   var step;
   while (step = path.shift()) {
       object = object[step];
   }
   return object;
}

get(obj, 'hello.you');
```